# Forgot to issue 1099-MISC form. Will FTB (or IRS) take away my business tax deductions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, california, general-partnership

I recently found out that as a business owner I had to issue form 1099-MISC to independent contractors, like, plumber who once fixed sink in our salon. Also, apparently I had to issue 1099-MISC because I was renting out premises where I do business.

However, back in 2011 I did not know that I had to issue 1099 for those two cases.

Now the FTB is inquiring about my missing 2012 tax return because back in 2011 I forgot to mark "Final" checkbox on my 565 form because we changed business structure from General Partnership to Sole proprietorship after the other partner left. I sent to FTB amended 2011 tax return with "Final" marked and everything else being the same. FTB told me that this 2011 tax return will go through their audit department.

**Will FTB possibly now take away all my tax deductions that I claimed back in 2011 and for which I did not issue form 1099?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're under audit - you should get a proper representation. I.e.: EA or CPA licensed in California and experienced with the FTB audit representation.

There's a penalty on failure to file form 1099, but it is with the IRS, not the FTB. If I remember correctly, it's something like $50 or $100 per instance.

Technically they can disqualify deductions claiming you paid under the table and no taxes were paid on the other side, however I doubt they'd do it in a case of simple omission of filing 1099 forms. Check with your licensed tax adviser.

Keep in mind that for the IRS 2011 is now closed, since the 3-year statute of limitations has passed. For California the statute is 4 years, and you're almost at the end of it. However since you're already under audit they may ask you to agree to extend it.